# Ethereum - Can we expect a stable job opportunity?

Tags: solidity

I am not sure if this is a right place for this type of questions.

I have done Java development and follow agile methodology. As you know we have sprints in which you would keep on releasing new features/update existing features every sprint which is normal for almost all the programming languages/frameworks we have now.

On the other hand for blockchain technologies, as the contracts are immutable, the very first time when you deploy the contract itself, should have been thoroughly tested and considered all the requirements and deploy it on ethereum network. Once it is deployed in PROD and live for months/years, there is no way to modify later as we might lose the data from the live contract.

So, I feel like we can not have agile development methodology for smart contracts.

From employee perspective, All jobs related to smart contracts development should be short-term related. We can not expect a long-term stable job opportunity!

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

That's why we have [Upgradeable Smart Contracts](https://hackernoon.com/upgradeable-smart-contracts-a7e9aef76fdd), some relying on proxy contracts that can be updated, some are kernel / acl based, some require governance for approval and many more.

And the "solidity" part is rather small in comparison to the rest of the application you're going to be building.